How does Mathematica calculate a fractional derivative?
The Riemann-Liouville fractional derivative of order $1/2$ of $x^{-1}$ is defined as 
$$
\mathcal{D}_x^{1/2} x^{-1} = \frac{1}{\Gamma(1/2)} \frac{d\;}{dx} \left[\int_0^x (x-\tau)^{-1/2}\tau^{-1} \,d\tau\right] .
$$
Since the above integral does not converge, I understand that this fractional derivative does not exists. However, when I ask Mathematica to calculate it using the command FractionalD, I obtain that the result is 
$$
\frac{-\log{x}+ \gamma+\psi^{(0)}(-1/2)}{2\sqrt{\pi} x^{3/2}} 
$$
where $\gamma$ is the Euler-Mascheroni constant and $\psi^{(0)}$ is the digamma function.
How did Mathematica arrive to this result?

Let try FractionalD[1/x, {x, 1/2}] /. x -> .5 , we have out 1.04272. On the other hand, we can evaluate  NFractionalD[1/x, {x, 1/2}, .5], and have out -605.36. It looks like a bug. :)

I don't know how much it helps but if you look at the definition of FractionalD:
GeneralUtilitiesPrintDefinitions@FractionalD` (run this twice)
Then go into the definition of iFractionalD -> FractionalDTable you will see a bunch of FractionalDTable definitions. I believe FractionalD is using one of these FractionalDTable definitions when FractionalD[1/x, {x, 1/2}] is called here

@ydd: Sorry, your code produces a syntax error"Syntax::tsntxi: "GeneralUtilitiesPrintDefinitions@FractionalD`" is incomplete; more input is needed. ".

@user64494 Sorry I messed up the backticks in the comment: GeneralUtilities`PrintDefinitions[FractionalD] the backtick needs to be between GeneralUtilities and PrintDefinitions. Make sure to run GeneralUtilities`PrintDefinitions[FractionalD] twice because it will come up blank the first time. Look here at Domen's comment for the same format but for FindSequenceFunction

@ydd: Sorry, this produces an empty notebook in red. Can you present the result of iFractionalD -> FractionalDTable in the forum?

This is System`FractionalD here if you download to local device you should be able to click on the notebook links to iFractionalD and then to FractionalDTable

@ydd: Sorry, all lines of the downloaded nb produce patched. After that FractionalDTable returns the input. I repeat can you present the result ofFractionalDTable in the forum? I am waiting for a rich in content reply.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

For some unknown to me reason I can't  submit comment in chat at the moment so I pesent a usual comment. Thank you, I see that nb in Wolfram Cloud. As far as I understand it, this is a table of some fractional derivatives, for example, FractionalDTable[Abs[z_],a,alpha_]:=Abs[z]/((z^alpha)*Gamma[2-alpha]); at the end of the table. I don't see any general definitions of FractionalD equivalent to the definition from the documentation . That's all. Sorry, I have nothing to discuss with you in such a manner. All the best.

This is rather a math than Mathematica question. As I understand it, the formula
 FractionalD[f[x], {x, a}]==FractionalD[Integrate[f[x], x], {x, a + 1}] 

which holds onder certain assumptions is used to this end i.e. to define the fractional derivative of order $1/2$  of $1/x$ (I don't have a reference at hand.). Indeed,
FractionalD[Integrate[1/x, x], {x, 3/2}


(EulerGamma - Log[x] + PolyGamma[0, -(1/2)])/(2 Sqrt[\[Pi]] x^(3/2))

where the integral converges. Hope that gap in the documentation will be filled in next versions of Mathematica.

The formula FractionalD[f[x], {x, a}]==FractionalD[Integrate[f[x], x], {x, a + 1}]  can be proven by integration by parts.

In the current documentation https://reference.wolfram.com/legacy/language/v14/ref/FractionalD.html under "Scope" is an example FractionalD[x^n, {x, 1/3}] which also includes the case n=-1.

@VaclavKotesovec: Did you think twice before having posted your comment? The question is not about that formula, but about its derivation. The definition from the documentation does not work in the case n=1 as shown in the question. If I have nothing to say, I don't say

My comment was not about the question, but about your sentence about "gap in the documentation".  And it is a case of n=-1 (not n=1). I will not respond to your further comments.

Thanks folks! I'm so used to the Caputo derivative that I didn't realize this works for the Riemann-Liouville definition.

@user101391:  Guy, the usage of FractionalD[f[x], {x, a}]==FractionalD[Integrate[f[x], x], {x, a + 1}]  seems highly likely.

@user101391: Unfortunately, CaputoD[x^(-1), {x, 1/2}] returns the input and "CaputoD::sing: Caputo fractional derivative of given order is not available for the input function.".
